# QuickFIX/J session hangs when using SSL and proxy

Tags: quickfixj

I am facing a strange problem. After a variable amount of time, my quickfixj session simply hangs without any error. The session seems to be locked because I cannot write anything to it (without exceptions on the log file) nor the server sends anything to me. The thread socket initiator shows that the sessions is logged in, but I cannot write anything on the socket because it seems to be locked.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Create a thread dump when the problem happens. When you got the thread dump, upload it somewhere and add a link to it in our question. Doesn't the session disconnect because of missing heartbeats? A message log would also be helpful. Please also upload somewhere and add link to it.

Comment: Hi @ChristophJohn, here's the link to the thread dump: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4bpyevdcrbdgmya/thread-dump-clean.txt?dl=0

Comment: @ChristophJohn Just updated the file, I uploaded the wrong one.

Comment: There is a deadlock in the dump, so that is the reason why it is blocked. Which version of QFJ are you using? It is blocking somewhere in the proxy handler. Is the connection maybe timing out when the error occurs?

Comment: @ChristophJohn I am using the latest version of QFJ. Specifically, the 2.3.0. The apache mina version is the 2.1.4 (the latest).

Comment: Discussion here, for future generations: https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj/issues/398